VBA get data from a sheet within multiple workbooks put into sheets within a singular workbook
I have the below VBA code which gets data from a sheet (Results) from multiple workbooks saved within the same filepath. The problem I am encountering is the data exceeds the row limit of 1048576 and  causes the VBA to stop. I need the VBA to keep pasting the data into the new workbook onto another sheet once the row limit is reached.
Sub GetDataFromTabIntoAnotherWorkbook()


On Error Resume Next
Const shName = "Results" '<< search for this sheet..
Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim L As Long, r As Long
Dim myPath

myPath = "filepath\"

Dim myFile
myFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets(1))
L = 1
Do While myFile <> ""
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)
    r = WB.Sheets(shName).UsedRange.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    WB.Sheets(shName).Rows("1:" & r).Copy
    myWB.Sheets(1).Cells(L, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    L = myWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    WB.Close False
    myFile = Dir()
Loop
Sheets(1).UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
myWB.Save
Range("A1").Select
myWB.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


Use a variable for the sheet you are working on. Add a condition before pasting, something like If L + r > 1048576 then if true add a new sheet and assign it to the sheet variable.
